# PHPUnit-Selenium FirefoxProfile settings

Tags: linux, firefox, selenium, automation, phpunit

I am getting a "Bad request" exception when starting a test run with Selenium WebDriver in Firefox. I traced this problem to hosts config file (using Linux). The hosts file on my machine has this line

> 127.0.0.1 something localhost

This works fine when I update hosts file as below

> 127.0.0.1 localhost something

But I cannot change this file. I found an issue related to this,

> https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=3280

People suggested solution for this as

> profile.setPreference(FirefoxProfile.ALLOWED_HOSTS_PREFERENCE,
>   "something");

But I am using phpunit-selenium framework and not sure where to place this line. Anyone please suggest me solution in phpunit-selenium framework